# Question about the voting example

Tags: remix

I am a beginner studying how to use Solidity in writing smart contract.

As I read the Solidity documentation, I would like to have a feel of how smart contract works using the [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/).

I am trying with the contract Ballot given in the [voting example](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html).

[image]

According to my understanding, after I have created the contract, I would be the the chairperson with address `msg.sender`

And I can give right to other voters using the `giveRightToVote` function by entering their address.

What I am not sure here is how I can create another voter with different address in Remix IDE. If I click create, another contract would be generated voting for different proposals.

Can someone please teach me what I should do in order to create a new voter or point out if I have misunderstanding in concepts. Thank you very much.

Comment: are you using javascript VM as the environmnet?

Comment: yes, I have used the original setting.

Comment: yes, I would like to create other voter as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Run tab and select another account from account field and try. There are five test accounts with 100 ETH in each.

[image]

Comment: Should I create a new contract by clicking create or clicking at address?

Comment: No need you can just use the functions available in already deployed contract